# Генерация массивов Костаса заданного размера

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Существует ли какой-то алгоритм для создания массивов Костаса нужного размера?

Comment: Да, если этот нужный размер на единицу меньше простого числа ;) Ты бы хоть ссылку привёл, что это за массивы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы создания массивов Костаса произвольного размера неизвестны.

Остаётся brute-force: генерировать n! перестановок, для каждой перестановки строить треугольник разностей и проверять, что его строки не содержат одинаковых чисел. Сложность `n!*n^3`.